# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'display') at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, function, foreach, contains, display

js file

```
> const filterOption=document.querySelector('.filter-todo');
> 
> filterOption.addEventListener('click',filterTodo);

> function deleteCheck(e){
> const item=e.target;
> 
>     //DELETE TODO
> if (item.classList[0]==='trash-btn'){
> const todo=item.parentElement;
>         //Animation
> todo.classList.add('fall');  //to create an class for transition
> todo.addEventListener('transitionend',function(){
> todo.remove();  //it will wait until the animation is finished and then remove it.
>         });
>      }
> 
>      //CheckMark
> if (item.classList[0]==='complete-btn'){
> const todo=item.parentElement;
> todo.classList.toggle('completed');
>      }
> }
```

--

### *****Error function *********

```
function filterTodo(e){
   let todos=todoList.childNodes;
   todos.forEach((todo)=>{
      switch(filterOption.value){
         case "all":
            todo.style.display='flex';
            break;

         case 'completed':
            if(todo.classList.contains("completed")){
               todo.style.display='flex';
            }else{
               todo.style.display='none';
            }  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EOMX.png)
         
         case 'uncompleted': 
            if(!todo.classList.contains('completed')){
               todo.style.display='flex';
            }else{
               todo.style.display='none';
            }
            
    
      }
   })


     
}
```

--

### Here error is displaying in the   todo.style.display='flex'    and in    if(todo.classList.contains("completed")

html

> ```
>         <div class="select">
>             <select  name="todos" class="filter-todo">
>                   <option value="all">all</option>
>                 <option value="completed">completed</option>
>                 <option value="uncompleted">uncompleted</option>
>             </select>
> ```

To filter the element by eliminating this error. Where 'all' will display the all the elements , 'complete' will display the completed elements and 'uncomplete' will display the uncompleted elements.